# JS : Focus disappears instantly when opening web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm now using w2ui library and JQuery for the web.

When I use w2ui for making a form, it works fine on Internet Explorer.
On Chrome, however, it loses focus instantly that I'm not able to know where the focus is, even when I click on a certain input box!

Then, when I refresh, it suddenly shows the focus.. It is so weird.. I don't understand what is happening on it.

Nothing shows on the console, no logs, no errors appears. Is Chrome working something different with IE when loading?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="w2ui-page page-0">
    <div>
        <div id="title1" class="sub_title"></div>
        <!--<div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6">
            <label for="connect_type">Connect Type</label>
            <div>
                <select name="connect_type">
                    <option value="0">udp</option>
                    <option value="1">tcp</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>-->
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6">
            <label for="registrar_ip">Registrar</label>
            <div>
                <input name="registrar_ip" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" />:
                <input name="registrar_port" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6" id="proxy">
            <label for="proxy_ip">Proxy</label>
            <div>
                <input name="proxy_ip" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" />:
                <input name="proxy_port" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6">
            <label for="outbound_proxy_ip">Outbound Proxy</label>
            <div>
                <input name="outbound_proxy_ip" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" />:
                <input name="outbound_proxy_port" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6">
            <div>
                <input name="loose_routing_enabled" type="checkbox" />
                <span> Use Loose Routing</span>
            </div>
        </div>-->
        <!--<div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6">
            <label for="connect_type2">Connect Type</label>
            <div>
                <select name="connect_type2">
                    <option value="0">udp</option>
                    <option value="1">tcp</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>-->
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6" id="presence">
            <label for="presence_ip">Presence</label>
            <div>
                <input name="presence_ip" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" />:
                <input name="presence_port" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6">
            <label for="sms_ip">SMS</label>
            <div>
                <input name="sms_ip" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" />:
                <input name="sms_port" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6">
            <label for="outbound_proxy_sms_ip">Outbound Proxy<br>For SMS</label>
            <div>
                <input name="outbound_proxy_sms_ip" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" />:
                <input name="outbound_proxy_sms_port" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6">
            <div>
                <input name="loose_routing2_enabled" type="checkbox" />
                <span> Use Loose Routing</span>
            </div>
        </div>-->
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6" id="sms_user_field" style="display: none">
            <label for="sms_user">SMS User</label>
            <div>
                <input name="sms_user" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div id="title2" class="sub_title"></div>
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6">
            <label for="private_registrar_ip">Registrar</label>
            <div>
                <input name="private_registrar_ip" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" />:
                <input name="private_registrar_port" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6" id="private_proxy">
            <label for="private_proxy_ip">Proxy</label>
            <div>
                <input name="private_proxy_ip" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" />:
                <input name="private_proxy_port" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6">
            <label for="private_outbound_proxy_ip">Outbound Proxy</label>
            <div>
                <input name="private_outbound_proxy_ip" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" />:
                <input name="private_outbound_proxy_port" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6" id="private_presence">
            <label for="private_presence_ip">Presence</label>
            <div>
                <input name="private_presence_ip" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" />:
                <input name="private_presence_port" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6">
            <label for="private_sms_ip">SMS</label>
            <div>
                <input name="private_sms_ip" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" />:
                <input name="private_sms_port" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span6">
            <label for="private_outbound_proxy_sms_ip">Outbound Proxy<br>For SMS</label>
            <div>
                <input name="private_outbound_proxy_sms_ip" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" />:
                <input name="private_outbound_proxy_sms_port" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="w2ui-buttons">
    <button class="btn" name="save">Save</button>
    <button class="btn" name="reset">Cancel</button>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if html code is helpful for assistant..

Comment: Please add the necessary code.

Comment: chrome and IE definitely support different ways of setting initial focus, and also have timing differences that can affect things.

Comment: Agreeing with karthick-- you need to add code.  Incidentally, you can find the currently focused element with `document.activeElement`.

Comment: Thank you all. It looks like the focus is not really gone, but it just doesn't show up at first time I join the web page. Then after refresh , alt+tab, or something else leaving the web page and coming back, it suddenly shows focus..

Comment: @AlexanderNied I tried your method, and it shows that 'body' has the focus..